# python regex: capturing group within OR

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python and the `re` module to parse some strings and extract a 4 digits code associated with a prefix. Here are 2 examples of strings I would have to parse:

```
str1 = "random stuff tokenA1234 more stuff"
str2 = "whatever here tokenB5678 tokenA0123 and more there"
```

tokenA and tokenB are the prefixes and 1234, 5678, 0123 are the digits I need to grab. token A and B are just an example here. The prefix can be something like an address `http://domain.com/` (tokenA) or a string like `Id:` (`'[Ii]d:?\s?'`) (tokenB).

My regex looks like:

```
re.findall('.*?(?:tokenA([0-9]{4})|tokenB([0-9]{4})).*?', str1)
```

When parsing the 2 strings above, I get:

```
[('1234','')]
[('','5678'),('0123','')]
```

And I'd like to simply get `['1234']` or `['5678','0123']` instead of a tuple.
How can I modify the regex to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get tuples as a result since you have more than 1 capturing group in your regex. See [`re.findall` reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, **return a list of groups**; this will be **a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group**.

So, the solution is **to use only one capturing group**.

Since you have tokens in your regex, you can use them inside a group. Since only tokens differ, `([0-9]{4})` part is common for both, just use an alternation operator between tokens put into a *non-capturing group*:

```
(?:tokenA|tokenB)([0-9]{4})
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The regex means:

- `(?:tokenA|tokenB)` - match but not capture `tokenA` or `tokenB`
- `([0-9]{4})` - match and capture into Group 1 four digits

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vALSDP):

```
import re
s = "tokenA1234tokenB34567"
print(re.findall(r'(?:tokenA|tokenB)([0-9]{4})', s))
```

Result: `['1234', '3456']`

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
re.findall(r"token[AB](\d{4})", s)
```

Put `[AB]` inside a character class, so that it would match either `A` or `B`